# Blazor data annotations with entity framework not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, data-annotations

I've done a fair amount of research on this but cannot find anything recent that either A) solves my issue or B) tells me my issue is unsolvable.

I'm building a Blazor Server application with Entity Core (DB First) and am trying to add data annotations/validation to the properties.  Only when I add the annotations to the generated class from entity does it work.

Here is what I have:

Entity Generated Class (shortened)

```
namespace SC2.AdvisorMasterData.Models
{
    public partial class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {

        }

        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Metadata Class

```
namespace SC2.AdvisorMasterData.Models
{
    [ModelMetadataType(typeof(ICompanyMetaData))]
    public partial class Company : ICompanyMetaData { }

    public interface ICompanyMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "{0} should have three or more letters")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As I said, if I take the annotations from the metadata class on the Name property and move them to the generated class it works.  However, if I regen the entity models, this obviously all disappears which is not ideal at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried starting an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose)?

Comment: No I haven't but due to the lack of response I'm going to assume that should be my next step.  Thank you.